# Using VPN with my camera

Tags: vpn

I have been using a VPN with my camera for about a year and everything worked perfectly. Recently my VPN subscription expired. I renewed my subscription but now I cannot view in the surveillance mode on my IPad. If I turn the VPN off everything works perfectly again. I can still view new video clips just no surveillance . Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend migration to Superuser

Comment: What kind of VPN are you using? If you're using it to connect a remote device to your home network where the camera is, then a subscription VPN makes no sense. Additionally, how is video stored? Is it on the camera? In the cloud? On a server? Are you using a VMS like Milestone?